# Setup celery worker and celery beat (django app) on AWS ECS

Tags: django, celery, amazon-ecs, celerybeat

I have a Django app with celery worker and beat, and I'm having a hard time trying to set up celery on ECS (The configuration of the Django app on ECS was pretty straightforward, no problems).

**1)** What kind of **service** should I use for the *worker* and the *beat*: `REPLICA` or `DAEMON`?

[image: service]

**2)** What command could I use to the *Healthcheck* on the **task definition** configuration?

[image: task_definition]

I tried using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) and also simply calling the `celery` command directly in the command section of the task definition.

I don't know what exactly I am missing...

- Supervisor configuration files:

**supervisor.conf**:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                      ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; supervisord log file
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; maximum size of logfile before rotation
logfile_backups=10          ; number of backed up logfiles
loglevel=debug               ; info, debug, warn, trace
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; pidfile location
nodaemon=false              ; run supervisord as a daemon
minfds=1024                 ; number of startup file descriptors
minprocs=200                ; number of process descriptors
user=root                   ; default user
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor/            ; where child log files will live

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

**celeryworker.conf**:

```
[program:celery]
command=/start-worker.sh

directory=/app
user=myuser
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/app_logs/celery-worker.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/app_logs/celery-worker.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600

stopasgroup=true

priority=1000
```

**celerybeat.conf**:

```
[program:celerybeat]
command=/start-beat.sh

directory=/app
user=myuser
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/app_logs/celery-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/app_logs/celery-beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
process group.

stopasgroup=true

priority=999
```

- Running scripts:

**start-worker.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
celery -A my_app worker -l ${APP_LOG_LEVEL} -n worker.%%h
```

**start-beat.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
celery -A my_app beat -l ${APP_LOG_LEVEL} --workdir=/app --schedule django
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. Let say you are choosing `REPLICA`, without healthcheck command and without supervisord, what exactly doesn't work? container STOPPED? can you share logs?

Comment: @ItayB the container stopped with a healthcheck. It looks like it's working without healthcheck. I don't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created the Service with a **Minimal healthy percentage** = **0** and the Task Definition **without healthcheck** as pointed out by @ItayB.
I also removed the supervisor setup.